# Why is the referer from my server alway null?

Tags: apache, redirect, url-rewriting

I am trying to work out why my referrer from my server always seems to be blank. I have knocked together the following to test it:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url='https://www.whatismyreferer.com/'" />
        <meta name="referrer" content="origin" />
    </head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

When I go to this page I get this:

[image: whatsmyreferer]

Is this something that is being set at a server level in Apache? I have a case where I need to pass the referrer so finding out what is controlling this would be good.

Answer (score 0):

The referrer header (with the famous [referer spelling](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42630/referer-or-referrer)) is sent by the browser. If the browser decides not to send it (e.g. for privacy reasons) it just won't do. You should never rely on the header to be there. Even if you find configurations that currently work: The request is valid with or without this header. And browsers might change their opinion any time (they did: The header used to be omnipresent, not it's less present)

Comment: I am aware of all of that but it doesn't actually answer the question! Also it isn't me that is relying on it but (in my particular use case) Amazon who are expecting referral links to come from a specified domain.